# Importing ES6 modules with babeljs + requirejs

Tags: ecmascript-6, requirejs, babeljs

I just started trying *ES6* and i already got stuck with *ES6 modules*. I use *babeljs* for translating *ES6* into *ES5*. My understanding is, that babel uses *requirejs* module loader behind the scenes to make the `import` happen.

So i am trying to set up a very basic sample of module loading but i cannot get it working.

I want to import a module from `bar.js` into `index.html`. Those files have same parent directory.

index.html code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>React</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.22.1/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.2/require.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script type="text/babel">
      console.log("Here we go.");
      import {foo} from 'bar';
      console.log(typeof foo);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

bar.js code:

```
export function foo() {
    console.log("Foo it!");
}
```

I get following error:

> Uncaught Error: Module name "bar" has not been loaded yet for context:
>   _. Use require([])

Even more interesting thing happens when i change order of `require.min.js` and `babel.min.js` in the `<head>`. This time the `text/babel` script is not executed at all (no errors in console).

Could somebody, please, explain what is wrong? Or is this completely bad approach?

Please, do not suggest using bundlers like webpack. I dont want to use them yet.

Comment: Use bundlers like Webpack.

Comment: In provided example I don't see `bar.js` being included in html. Could you explain how you load bar.js file with the module you are importing.

Comment: @bognix You probably mean that the `<script>` tag is missing. But that's allright, module loaders do not use `<script>` tags to do the job. (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles)